# Check whether MySQL record exists based on 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a PHP system that needs to check whether a record exists.

I'm fine checking whether a record exist that matches a single column:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE s_id = '$myVar'")
```

However, I want to see whether there is an exact match for two columns in the database (a_id and s_id), while ignoring the match of the 3rd column.

Any ideas on how to check for a match on two parameters exist?

---

Thanks so much for taking a look - feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: So you've got 3 columns that could potentially match, but want to require that only 2 of the 3 must match?

Comment: Simpler than that - the check is just whether s_id = var1 and a_id = var2. Answer provided below. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE s_id = '$myVar' AND a_id= '$myVar2'")
```

Comment: d'oh, seems I was tragically close. Thanks @mike, you rock.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE s_id = '$myVar' AND a_id = '$myOtherVar'")
```

Comment: d'oh, seems I was tragically close. Thanks @payne, you rock.